# Moscow papyrus area of hemisphere

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I found this interesting text on wikipedia that explains how egyptians calculated the area of (supposedly) hemisphere, referred to as "basket". It is contained in the Moscow Papyrus. Here is the text:

> Example of calculating a basket. You are given a basket with a mouth of $4 \frac{1}{2}$. What is its surface? Take $\frac{1}{9}$ of $9$ (since) the basket is half an egg-shell. You get $1$. Calculate the remainder which is $8$. Calculate $\frac{1}{9}$ of $8$. You get $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{18}$. Find the remainder of this $8$ after subtracting $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{18}$. You get $7 + \frac{1}{9}$. Multiply $7 + \frac{1}{9}$ by $4 + \frac{1}{2}$. You get $32$. Behold this is its area. You have found it correctly.

Now I am trying to understand what all these numbers represent by imagining this "basket" and I have been unsuccessful. Maybe someone understands the logic behind all of this to explain in more detail?

**EDIT**

So to be more specific. The algorithm obviously works ignoring the small error compared to our current formula. They were very practical and didn't have sophisticated mathematical knowledge. So this is why I essentially want that whoever answers this forgets about our modern mathematics and thinks exclusively in the context of this algorithm and its operations to somehow make sense of this.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401332/analysis-of-moscow-mathematical-papyrus-problem-no-10 and to hsm, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13541/analysis-of-moscow-mathematical-papyrus-problem-no-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the diameter of the hemisphere is $d=4.5$  then

- Take $\frac19$ of $2d$ to give $\frac{2}{9}d$ leaving $\frac89$ of $2d$, i.e. $2d - \frac{2}{9}d = \frac{16}{9}d$
- Take $\frac19$ of $\frac{16}{9}d$ to give $\frac{16}{81}d$ leaving $\frac89$ of $\frac{16}{9}d$, i.e. $\frac{16}{9}d - \frac{16}{81}d = \frac{128}{81}d$
- Multiply $\frac{128}{81}d$ by $d$ to give $\frac{128}{81}d^2$

The suggestion is that the curved surface area of a hemisphere is about $\frac{128}{81}$ times the square of the diameter

We know the surface area of a sphere is  $4\pi r^2 = \pi d^2$, implying the curved surface area of a hemisphere is $2\pi r^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} d^2$

So this suggests that $\frac{\pi}{2} \approx \frac{8}{9} \times \frac{8}{9} \times 2 = \frac{128}{81}$ and thus $\pi \approx \frac{256}{81}$

Comment: In your final approximation for half of $\pi$ why do you multiply by $2$?

Comment: because I started with $2d$ (in the original, doubling $4\frac12$ to $9$)

Comment: Some say that this equation really refers to the surface area of a half-cylinder. How does that work out?

Comment: @Burt The curved surface area of a cylinder of diameter $d$ and height $\frac d2$ is also $ \frac\pi 2 d^2$ so it makes no difference to the $\pi \approx \frac{256}{81}$ conclusion

Comment: @Henry Do you have any insight into what could be the way of thinking with this algorithm? For instance I don't understand what is the logic behind doubling the diameter and saying ' (since) the basket is half an egg-shell '.

Comment: @MichaelMunta possibly there was a similar algorithm (since lost) for the surface area of a sphere - a whole egg-shell.  Or perhaps not.

Comment: That's what I thought, but why is the diameter doubled? I am trying to think intuitivelly like when you close half of the egg with the other half the diameter of the whole stays the same.

Comment: @Henry and also is there no information at all as to how they arrived at this algorithm?

Comment: @MichaelMunta We do not even know if the translation is correct: see for example https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086009000305 - though you could try yourself at http://www.math.buffalo.edu/mad/Ancient-Africa/egypt_moscow10.html

Comment: @Henry Ok, so we will never know. :) Just to make sure our current formulas and their explanations for areas of sphere/hemisphere have nothing to do with doubling the diameter?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a very long-winded way of saying that the surface area of a hemisphere is approximately
$$\frac{512}{81}r^2$$
which implies the approximation
$$\pi\approx\frac{256}{81}\approx 3.1605$$

For instance, this passage:

> Take $\frac{1}{9}$ of $9$ (since) the basket is half an egg-shell. You
>   get $1$. Calculate the remainder which is $8$. Calculate $\frac{1}{9}$
>   of $8$. You get $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{18}$.

is the ancient Egyptian way of saying "$9\times\frac89\times\frac19=\frac89$".

See [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) for more evidence that they valued prolixity over clarity.

Comment: What about the general logic of this process? Like what $\frac{1}{9}$ represents in this "basket"? Because the process just says calculate this and calculate that and we have an area.

Comment: As far as I can make out, $\frac19$ is a constant of the algorithm, and $9$ is twice the diameter of the hemisphere. The diameter comes in again at the end, giving you the dependence on $r^2$; the rest is just jumping through hoops to calculate $\frac{512}{81}$ without using any numerator greater than $2$.

Comment: "they valued prolixity over clarity"... elegant formula but do we have a real idea of the way these scribes were thinking ?

Comment: @tonyk Just wondering, where exactly in this text is the calculation of $\frac{512}{81}$?