# Moscow papyrus deriving approximation of $\pi$

Tags: math-history

I have posted a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585754/moscow-papyrus-area-of-hemisphere). What I am interested now is how to derive the approximation of $\pi$ from the following text:

> Example of calculating a basket. You are given a basket with a mouth of $4 \frac{1}{2}$. What is its surface? Take $\frac{1}{9}$ of $9$ (since) the basket is half an egg-shell. You get $1$. Calculate the remainder which is $8$. Calculate $\frac{1}{9}$ of $8$. You get $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{18}$. Find the remainder of this $8$ after subtracting $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{18}$. You get $7 + \frac{1}{9}$. Multiply $7 + \frac{1}{9}$ by $4 + \frac{1}{2}$. You get $32$. Behold this is its area. You have found it correctly.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Mathematical_Papyrus#Two_Geometry_Problems) states that this text corresponds to the following:

$${\displaystyle {\text{Area}}=\left({\frac {2\times 8}{9}}\right)^{2}\times ({\text{diameter}})^{2}={\frac {256}{81}}({\text{diameter}})^{2}}$$

And that this $${\displaystyle {\frac {256}{81}}\approx 3.16049}$$

is an Egyptian approximation of $\pi$.

Can anyone show how to get this approximation of $\pi$ from this text?

Comment: According to most historians, the Ancient Egypt used the formula (see [Rhind papyrus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhind_Mathematical_Papyrus#Book_II_%E2%80%93_Geometry): $A = (d - \dfrac d 9)^2$ for the area of the circle.

Comment: Comparing it with the modern one: $A = \pi \dfrac {d^2}{4}$ we have that: $\pi= 4(\dfrac 8 9)^2$.

Comment: I would say this is the same question