# The Moscow Papyrus Problem Ten - how can it be discussing a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, math-history

I heard about the Moscow Papyrus, which has problems from the ancient Egyptians. It is interesting! Problem ten talks about finding the surface area of a basket with an opening of $4\frac{1}{2}$. [This question discusses the problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585754/moscow-papyrus-area-of-hemisphere) Quoting the text from there:

> Example of calculating a basket. You are given a basket with a mouth of $4 \frac{1}{2}$. What is its surface? Take $\frac{1}{9}$ of $9$ (since) the basket is half an egg-shell. You get $1$. Calculate the remainder which is $8$. Calculate $\frac{1}{9}$ of $8$. You get $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{18}$. Find the remainder of this $8$ after subtracting $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{18}$. You get $7 + \frac{1}{9}$. Multiply $7 + \frac{1}{9}$ by $4 + \frac{1}{2}$. You get $32$. Behold this is its area. You have found it correctly.

I heard that some say that the question is really talking about the surface area of a cylinder. How can this be? It seems the answer given is 32 - how is this?

Is it because the "basket opening" is talking about the diameter of the basket, and we are assuming the height is the same as the diameter? I am assuming that we are discussing lateral surface, and that we don't care if the answer is off by a half or so.

Comment: I think all could be said from a mathematical point of view is explained in the answers and comments to the question you linked. If you are interested in historical matters, you should consider asking on https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I did not know that stack exchange site existed! Thanks!